# NSDecimalNumber to String prints nothing on UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsdecimalnumber

My model has

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDecimalNumber *totalSpent;
```

and when I log

```
 NSLog(@"totalSpent:%@", self.monthlySummaryModel.totalSpent);
```

I get

```
2014-12-02 12:59:47.287 app-ios[16741:60b] totalSpent:2037.01
```

Now I want to add this on `UILabel`

```
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *totalSpentLabel;
```

I assign value to it as

```
self.totalSpentLabel.text = [self.monthlySummaryModel.totalSpent stringValue];
```

but what I see on page is nothing
[image]

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the data was fetched from `API` and I had to update labels once data is fetched

```
self.monthlySummaryModel = [[MonthlySummaryModel alloc] initWithJson:monthlySummary];
            NSLog(@"totalSpent:%@", self.monthlySummaryModel.totalSpent);

            [self.tableView reloadData];
            [self setSummarySpentView];

- (void)setSummarySpentView {
    self.SummarySpentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:44 / 255.0f green:62 / 255.0f blue:80 / 255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    self.totalSpentLabel.text = [self.monthlySummaryModel.totalSpent stringValue];
}
```